# Can't start google compute instance with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

### TLDR

I'm just trying to start up a simple vm and it terraform tells me I don't have sufficient permissions. Keep in mind I have a Trial account (and like $290 left of sweet sweet free money).

### Details

provider.tf

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "My First Project"
  region      = "us-east1"
}
```

resource.tf

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
  name         = "terraform-instance"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"
  zone      = "us-east1-c"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    # A default network is created for all GCP projects
    network       = "default"
    access_config {
    }
  }
}
```

Error

```
Error: Error loading zone 'us-east1-c': googleapi: Error 403: Permission denied on resource project My First Project., forbidden
```

### My Trouble Shooting

- I tried switching us-east1-c for other zones and tried us-central1 with different zones. Always got the same error.
- I'm passing the credentials with`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable and I know I'm passing it in correctly cause when I change the filename it breaks and says something like "that filename doesn't exist"
- I've tried different server types (n1-standard-1, n1-highcpu-16)
- **I've tried so many different IAM permissions** of particular note I tried Compute Admin, Compute Admin with Service Account User, and Compute Instance Admin and Service Account Admin.

Concerning the last point. I used

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT NAME> \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format='table(bindings.role)' \
--filter="bindings.members:<KEY NAME>"
```

And got this output

```
ROLE
roles/compute.admin
roles/compute.instanceAdmin
roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1
roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

#### But wait there's more

I went through [this link](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/managing-gcp-projects-with-terraform) and added all the permissions they suggested using the aforementioned key (except for all the ones that have to do with billing cause the organization is my school). When I checked the roles again I saw that it had added `roles/storage.admin`. Produced the same error though.

#### Update

A billing account is linked to my account and now the roles are this. AND IT STILL doesn't work

```
roles/billing.projectManager
roles/compute.admin
roles/compute.instanceAdmin
roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1
roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
roles/storage.admin
```

Comment: Just make sure billing is enabled. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#confirm_billing_is_enabled_on_a_project

Comment: Your troubleshooting only confirmed that it is finding the credentials file, not that the credentials within that file are correct or have sufficient privileges to deploy a VM. I recommend taking a careful look at the credentials that you are using there

Comment: I was fairly certain the credentials were the problem. I'm asking what the problem is with them. Also I have billing enabled on the project as a whole.